# How I convert numerical digit to bengali digit in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, localization, number-formatting, foundation

I need to convert  numerical digit to bengali digit.
if my input 12,then output ১২ .
I am trying to start it using regular expression,

```
NSArray *digitArray=@[@"90", @"10", @"32"];
NSError *error;
NSString *pattern = @"^[0-9]*$";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:pattern
                                                                           options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                             error:&error];
```

But I don't understand which process I follow to implement the conversion.

Comment: If it's every digit you could use `NSRange`, and if the string isn't too long you could loop through all the characters and replace the numerical ones

Comment: If I use loop,complexity is increase because I have to use a huge number of digit.So, if any other way without using loop,please suggest.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a number formatter with specific locale, like following:

```
NSLocale *locale = [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"bn_BD"];
NSNumberFormatter *fmt = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
fmt.locale = locale;
NSString *bengaliString = [fmt stringFromNumber:@20];
```

Where `@20` is a `NSNumber` literal.